# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Need advice

I'm using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3

I'm trying create post on admin, with validation for title and content presence. but when i create the post the error of validation raise, even if i fill for title and content.

this is my code

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  ...
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
module Admin
  class PostsController < ::ApplicationController
    layout 'admin'
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :publish, :unpublish]

   def new
    @post = Post.new
   end

   def create
     @post = Post.new(post_params)
     @post.user = current_user

     respond_to do |format|
       if @post.save
         format.html { redirect_to admin_post_path(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
       else
         format.html { render action: 'new' }
         format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_post
     @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
   end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :published)
   end
  end
end
```

and in my log raise WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Post: title, content.

Thank's

Comment: Are you sure you're using Rails 4? That mass assignment error shouldn't be appearing unless you're on Rails 3. Make sure to start your server with `bundle exec` to avoid loading the wrong version by mistake

Comment: David is right. If this is a Rails 3 to 4 app being converted, there could be some legacy settings in your environment. Can you update your post with your `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb`? It's also important to note that the only parameters that will get through to the post are the ones you permit in the `post_params` method. So if you need to pass more from the form, update the method to accept them.

Comment: Another possibility -- do you have the 'protected_attributes' gem in your Gemfile? If so, you should either remove it or add rails 3 style attr_accessible calls from your model.

Comment: Can you share your servers log?